# Running Lua script on OpenWRT directly (without running lua first)

Tags: lua, openwrt

On OpenWRT, I have a Lua script `on_new_device.lua` that runs fine if I execute `lua on_new_device.lua`; however, I'd like to run it simply by executing `./on_new_device.lua`.

Executing `./on_new_device.lua` returns this error...

```
root@router:~# ./on_new_device.lua
-ash: ./on_new_device.lua: not found
```

The file has execute permissions...

```
root@router:~# ls -la ./on_new_device.lua
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          1094 Jun 18 11:06 ./on_new_device.lua
```

The file starts with `#!/usr/bin/lua`...

```
root@router:~# head -1 ./on_new_device.lua
#!/usr/bin/lua
```

How can I execute this file directly?

Comment: Remove `noexec` disk mount option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, the problem was that the lua script was created on a Windows machine and had \r\n line endings.  Saving the file with \n line endings solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Can you wrap it in a script?

Copy this into a test.ash file:

```
#!/bin/ash

/usr/bin/lua /[path]/on_new_device.lua
```

Then chmod 755 on test.ash, and then you can run:

```
./test.ash
```